# NetAnim: cannot connect to X server

Tags: xserver

I have Ubuntu machine with NS3 and NetAnim installed.

When trying to run NetAnim with the command ./NetAnim, it does not run and I always get this message "NetAnim: cannot connect to X server".

I have been trying to fix it for two weeks but could not succeed. I tried many options including the following to run the server:

- `xset -q`
- `ps -e | grep Xorg`
- `export DISPLAY=":0.0"`
- `apt-get install xserver-xorg xorg -y`
- `startx`

However, the problem is still the same.

Appreciate your help as I am stuck in my work...